# Are the IN statements in this query redundant?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I've been given a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM dayTable
LEFT JOIN ProcessTable firstprocess
ON dayTable.id = a.daytablefkid 
AND firstprocess.processid in (1234)
AND firstprocess.daytablefkid 
     IN (SELECT id 
         FROM daytable  
         WHERE dayTable.DateFrom > @dateFrom 
         AND dayTable.DateTo < @dateTo)

LEFT JOIN ProcessTable secondprocess
ON daytable.id = secondprocess.daytablefkid
and secondprocess.processid in (4567)
    IN (SELECT id 
        FROM daytable 
        WHERE dayTable.DateFrom > @dateFrom 
        AND dayTable.DateTo < @dateTo)


WHERE dayTable.DateFrom > @dateFrom AND dayTable.DateTo < @dateTo
```

tHe first thing i noticed is that the first IN-statement "IN(XXXX)" in the joins can be converted to a WHERE-statement, but the second IN statement in both joins is a bit confusing because the same filtering is also done at the end on the query.

What I'm wondering if they are indeed redundant or can the resultset be different if they are removed?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your query, "dayTable.id = a.daytablefkid" should be "dayTable.id = firstprocess.daytablefkid"

Comment: That query's not valid. You need some column before the second `IN` in the second `JOIN`

Comment: When you know the processId of both processes (which seems to be the primary key), why do you need all these filtering at all? This query is very very very strange and seems to be highly overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `IN (SELECT id FROM daytable WHERE dayTable.DateFrom > @dateFrom AND dayTable.DateTo < @dateTo)`-parts are redundant, since you already joined on the daytable, on which you have the same `WHERE`-clause.

This query should give the same results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dayTable
LEFT JOIN ProcessTable firstprocess
  ON dayTable.id = firstprocess.daytablefkid 
    AND firstprocess.processid = 1234
LEFT JOIN ProcessTable secondprocess
  ON daytable.id = secondprocess.daytablefkid
    AND secondprocess.processid = 4567
WHERE 
  dayTable.DateFrom > @dateFrom 
  AND dayTable.DateTo < @dateTo
```

Answer (score 0):

one more option optimization of request

```
SELECT * 
FROM dayTable 
  LEFT JOIN ProcessTable process ON dayTable.id = process.daytablefkid 
    AND process.processid IN (1234, 4567)
WHERE dayTable.DateFrom > @dateFrom AND dayTable.DateTo < @dateTo
```